# Conditional selecting from a JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, json2html

I'm trying to select and display specific JSON data within an array. The data looks like this:

```
{ "thingys" : [
  {
    "type" : "thingy1",
    "text" : "this is thingy1"
  },
  {
    "type" : "thingy2",
    "text" : "this is thingy2"
  },
  {
    "type" : "thingy3",
    "text" : "this is thingy3"
  }
]}
```

I'm using json2html, and I would normally use something like

```
{"tag":"div","html":"${thingys.text}"}
```

This would be fine, but I want to be able to specify that I want ${thingys.text} where ${thingys.type} == "thingy3". How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way to achieve something like this would be to include an inline function to process the the "thingys" Something like this

```
var transforms = {
'main': {"tag":"div","children":function() {

  var out = [];
  for(var i=0; i < this.thingys.length; i++)
     if(this.thingys[i].test == "thingy3") out.push(this.things[i]);

  return( json2html.transform(out,transforms.thing) );
}},

'thing':{"tag":"div","html":"${text}"}
};
```