# json2html how to exclude line when field doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, json2html

In [json2html](http://json2html.com/), if I define an element in the template that doesn't exist in the JSON, I want to "display: none;" or perhaps better, just exclude the line in some way.

**Example Template:**

```
{"tag":"div","children":[
    {"tag":"div","html":"First Name: ${first_name}"},
    {"tag":"div","html":"Middle Name: ${middle_name}"},
    {"tag":"div","html":"Last Name: ${last_name}"}
]}
```

**Result:**

```
First Name: John
Middle Name: 
Last Name: Doe
```

If a middle name doesn't exist in the json, I don't want it to have a `<div>` entry for the middle name, but instead skip that line.

**What I'd like:**

```
First Name: John
Last Name: Doe
```

Comment: Do you need a javascript or jquery code??

Comment: I think I need something to go in the template, which seems to look like javascript in other help questions.  json2html itself uses jquery, so that could also be used if it would make it easier.  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847085/conditional-selecting-from-a-json-array  Perhaps I added too many tags to this question and should have just limited it to json2html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is:

Let the divs have ids/classes and I would suggest you to change the template layout in this format:

```
{"tag":"div","class":"container","children":[
  {"tag":"div","class":"field","children":[
      {"tag":"span", "html":"First Name:"},
      {"tag":"span","html":"${first_name}"}
    ]
  },
  {"tag":"div","class":"field","children":[
      {"tag":"span", "html":"Middle Name:"},
      {"tag":"span","html":"${middle_name}"}
    ]
  },
  {"tag":"div","class":"field","children":[
      {"tag":"span", "html":"Last Name:"},
      {"tag":"span","html":"${last_name}"}
    ]
  }
]}
```

After that gets processed, you can write a small code(jquery) like this:

```
 $(".container div").each(function(){
   var childs = $(this).children();
   if($(childs[1]).is(":empty")){
     $(this).hide();
   }
 });
```

I think it should work.

Hope it helps

Comment: I had a problem with $(childs)[1].is(":empty").  It gave me a "TypeError: $(...)[1].is is not a function".  But childs[1].innerHTML seemed to work, so I was able to compare against that.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, since the template gets repeated for each object in the json, using an id would probably not be good.  Instead, a class might be a better pick with only the container needing to be defined.  So "class":"container", then $(".container div").

Comment: @JeffG Ya its actually `$(childs[1])` and not `$(childs)[1]`. I corrected the solution.

Comment: Indeed, $(childs[1]) fixed it.  Great :)  Just wondering what the difference is (accuracy/performance/...) of using is(":emtpy") vs length === 0 or === ""?

Comment: I don't not know the answer to that, but I think it checks if there is any HTML and text in the div and if none of the are there, then returns true. To be more accurate, it comes from the css origin,

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this within the json2html template as so

```
{"tag":"div","children":[
   {"tag":"div","html":"First Name: ${first_name}"},
   {"tag":"div","html":"Middle Name: ${middle_name}","class":function(){
      if(!this.middle_name) return("hide");
   }},
   {"tag":"div","html":"Last Name: ${last_name}"}]}
```

then simply add this css

```
.hide {display:none;}
```